# System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datetime

I  am writing an application in c#.net that works with sql DB. I have 5 fields - DateTime. When i am in debug mode , i see that the DateTime fields are correct , but when i run the application i get the next exception - {System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.}

the code -

```
         try
            {
                DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
                date = AllEventsSortedList[0].dateTime;
                foreach (Event m485 in _485List)
                {
                    CycleTbl nCycle = new CycleTbl();
                    nCycle._485_DateTime = m485.dateTime;
                    nCycle.OrderNumber = m485.OrderNumber;
                    nCycle.Source = m485.Source;
                    nCycle.Dest = m485.Destination;
                    foreach (Event m412 in _412List)
                    {
                        if ((m485.dateTime.Year == m412.dateTime.Year) && (m485.dateTime.Month == m412.dateTime.Month) && (m485.dateTime.Day == m412.dateTime.Day))
                            nCycle._412_DateTime = (DateTime)m412.dateTime;
                    }
                    foreach (Event m500 in _500List)
                    {
                        if ((m485.dateTime.Year == m500.dateTime.Year) && (m485.dateTime.Month == m500.dateTime.Month) && (m485.dateTime.Day == m500.dateTime.Day))
                            nCycle._500_DateTime = (DateTime)m500.dateTime;
                    }
                    foreach (Event m502 in _502list)
                    {
                        if ((m485.dateTime.Year == m502.dateTime.Year) && (m485.dateTime.Month == m502.dateTime.Month) && (m485.dateTime.Day == m502.dateTime.Day))
                        {
                            nCycle._502_DateTime = m502.dateTime;
                            nCycle.LGVNumber = (int)m502.LGVNumber;
                        }
                    }

                    nCycle._502_DateTime = (DateTime)date;
                    LgvDB.CycleTbls.InsertOnSubmit(nCycle);
                    LgvDB.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in building the table." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            }
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?
thank you.

Comment: My problem was resolved when i put in the value that doesn't exist in the list DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.NET DateTime range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx):

> The DateTime value type represents
>   dates and times with values ranging
>   from 12:00:00 midnight, January 1,
>   0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through
>   11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D.
>   (C.E.).

[SQL Server datetime range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx):

> January 1, 1753, through December 31,
>   9999

SQL Server 2008 introduced the [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) datatype which has a greater range in line with .NET DateTime.